# Jmeter properties configuration adding UseConcMarkSweepGC & DisableExplicitGC

Tags: java, jmeter, garbage-collection, performance-testing

Can anyone help me how to add these `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` and `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` on my Jmeter configuration, Current the issue I'm encountering upon generating 6000 request per minute and after few hours request is decreasing. I tried to update this file /data/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter unfortunately its not working. Your response is highly appreciated.

FYI: I'm using Jmeter 5.3 version

[image: Jmeter configuration]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that this is due to garbage collection and [G1 garbage collector](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html) is to blame you can comment out the line which tells JMeter to use it:

[image]

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter and Java so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@jmeter.apache.org/msg12970.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)